# Creating a CUSTOM exe file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a simple game engine just for the experience of it. I've realized, though, that I have no idea how to export the user's custom game as its own standalone executable. For example (this is not my actual game engine, it just provides an easy reference for discussion), suppose we had the following very simple code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void RunGame(string question, string answer)
{
    string submission;
    cout << question << endl;
    getline(cin, submission);
    if (submission == answer)
        cout << "Correct!";
    else
        cout << "Wrong!";
}

int main()
{
    string question;
    string answer;

    cout << "Enter Question:" << endl;
    getline(cin, question);
    cout << "Enter Answer:" << endl;
    getline(cin, answer);


    RunGame(question, answer);
}
```

In this example the user gets to create their own customized bit of trivia, and then can test it immediately afterwards when RunGame is called. Now I want to be able to save their game with the trivia information they provided as its own .exe (basically it will perform from the call to RunGame onwards). How would I go about doing that?

To be clear, this isn't a question about what is the easiest/fastest way to make a game. It is looking for how to build a standalone, executable file from within code.

Comment: Have you tried placing the Customer's data into a data file rather than in the executable?

Comment: Why do you want the trivia as an executable?  Are you going to *execute* the trivia data?  *(Usually, data is not executed, but read or written by a program.)*

Comment: The data file can be installed along with an executable.  Many installer programs can create installations that include executable and data files.

Comment: @ArcaneLight He did read your question and downvoted because you're asking for something that is not done in practice.  He suggested a better approach of saving the data.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I probably came across too strongly there, I just felt (and still do) that my question wasn't understood, in which case I don't mind a downvote so long as there's an explanation pointing out the ambiguity so I can be clearer.

Comment: @Matt But I'm not sure what you mean about it not being done in practice. This is a very common function of Game Engines. Unity, Unreal, Cryengine...these all export your custom-made game as its own standalone executable. This is a very common practice.

Comment: @ArcaneLight: I did not downvote you.  I'm only asking questions to get a better understanding.  Writing a program to create executables can be complicated.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Fair enough, my apologies for jumping the gun. I'm not surprised to hear that it can be complicated, is there any reference you could point me towards?

Comment: You have to primary approaches:  1) Write up the data as a C or C++ data statements and compile it in a `main` program.  2) Researching the executable file format and figuring out how to add data into an executable file.  Item 2 may get difficult, especially if you have adjust any addresses (addresses of function or static data).  For example, if the executable expects a data table of 20 and you expand it to 40, then offsets will need to be adjusted.

Comment: @ArcaneLight What Unreal and others do is use their engine and user developed data together.  The exe itself doesn't contain all the information to run the game.  It will read in data (like 3D models, textures, etc) and display them using built in functions.  In your case save the questions and answers and have the engine read in the information.  Then each user can have their own files and one executable can read them and use them.

Comment: Some UNIX-like platforms have an `unexec` function that creates an executable from the current state of the program, but AFAIK, Windows doesn't have anything like it.

Comment: Even as a learning experience, it's really, really hard to create a correct executable file, and it gives almost no benefit over using a separate data file. Do you think that you could go over the benefits you hope getting from custom executables?

Comment: If you want to generate an executable, you need a compiler stack. It is pretty easy creating your own language and using LLVM for it.

Comment: @ArcaneLight None of those engines "export your game to an executable", they generate code that can be compiled or customize a stock player-executable and put the data into data files. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html "For the Windows build target, an executable file (.exe) will be built, along with a Data folder which contains all the resources for your application"

Comment: @kfsone Thank you, that makes a lot of sense with what everyone else is saying about making executables not being worth it. So my design should be around creating a _stock_ _executable_ _+_ _data_ which, together, are able to stand alone. The engine creates a new copy of each and edits the data, the stock executable reads from the data and runs accordingly. Thanks again, I think I can go from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to store data inside the .exe itself:

An executable has a header that defines its size, boundaries and other useful stuff to the Operating System, so, essentially, the operating system knows where the code and data sections start and end, and it finally uses this information to load up the .exe to memory when it is asked to run.

Since the Operating System knows (besides the .exe's file size) where the executable actually ends, this also means that any data pasted *after* the .exe's "calculated" end (by headers) won't negatively effect the binary. It will still load and execute just fine.

You can abuse this property to concatenate data after the end of the executable.

I'll leave you with this test, using Windows' bundled WordPad application as a 'host' for some other data:

- Go to **C:\Windows** and copy **write.exe** (WordPad) to another folder, so we can experiment without damaging anything.
- Bring to that folder another file, any file will do. In my example, the data file will be a PDF called "myfancyfile.pdf"
- Now, open a command prompt and use the COPY command to stitch both files together, making sure the .exe comes first:

  ```
  copy /B write.exe+myfancyfile.pdf mynewprogram.exe
  ```

  - copy's **/B** flag means "binary copy", so essentially both files were pasted together without any kind of text or data conversion.
- Try to run "mynewprogram.exe". Realize it runs just fine :-)

Self-modifying your .exe with data is not only feasible, it won't negatively effect functionality. Having that said, it is still a ugly way to persist data.

Have fun coding your solution.

Comment: OP can also modify global strings/arrays if he adds some sort of marker to find them inside of the `.exe`.

Comment: How does the program know where the appened data is?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you, with that and kfsone's comment above I think I have my answer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews here's an example on how you can let the program know where to find/update the data inside its .exe ||

(1) have your program have logic to find a pattern inside its own file, like a marker, example: !DATA!<string>#DATA#" // (2) compile it. // (3) append it with your data marker, your program is ready and shippable now // (4) whenever it runs, it will find the data marker, with data inside ir or not. Use your own coded methods to update/delete that data.

Comment: This is a horrible answer and shouldn't be marked as an answer. Windows Portable Executable format is well defined and one doesn't just `COPY /B` stuff onto it. Sure it can work but it is a compatiblity nightmare (next Windows Update can decide to stop loading files with invalid data at the end), it invalidates digital signature on signed EXE files, and it will probably trip literally every anti-virus software.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this. A better way is to save the trivia in some custom format (for example, .txt, .dat, ..).

Then the game just handles this data.

So first think about the format inside of the .txt for example.

Lets say at first theres a number, indicating which entry this is. Second follows the question and after that the answer follows. This, you must decide for yourself.

## Example trivia-data.txt

```
1
How old is actor X from show Y?
32 years
2
...
...
```

---

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::endl
#include <fstream>  // std::ifstream, std::ofstream
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // create file
    ofstream ofile("trivia-data.txt");

    // define your data
    int num_of_question = 1;
    string question, answer;
    getline(cin, question);
    getline(cin, answer);

    // write your data to the file
    ofile << num_of_question << '\n';
    ofile << question << '\n';
    ofile << answer << '\n';

    // close the file
    ofile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Now that you created your data you just have to build your program in a way you would like to present this. Instead of writing to a file, you should read from a file and print the questions out and compare answers and what not. Look up ***`std::ifstream`*** for reading your file.

At the start you could ask your user if he would like to create a quiz or play one that already exists.

---

## Edit:

Since this sounds a lot like homework I just provide some pseudo code.

I'd go for an approach like this(pseudo code):

```
print "Would you like to create(c) or play(p) a quiz? Answer(c/p): "
input = get_input() // 'c' or 'p'
if input == 'c'
    // now do what I posted with some loops to create a couple of questions
else
    print "Please provide an URL to the quiz-data you would like to play: "
    url = get_input() // C:/test.txt
    // read in data, print out questions, do comparisons and print answers etc
```

This is infinitely easier than your approach and this also makes it possible for others to create quizzes not just you.

Comment: I tried convincing the OP of this route, but the OP insists on using an executable. :-(

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yeah I just saw that. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Building an executable is non-trivial. You will first need to comply with the target operating systems' ABI so that it can find your program's entry point. The next step will be deciding how your program is going to be able to access system resources: probably you'll want your executable to implement dynamic linking so it can access shared libraries, and you'll need to load the various .dll or .so files you're going to need. All the instructions you'll need to write for this will vary from OS to OS, you may need to introduce logic to detect the exact platform and make informed decisions, and you will need to vary for 32 vs 64 bit.

At this point you're about ready to start emitting the machine instructions for your game.

A reasonable alternative here is (as done by Unity) to provide a "blank" executable with your engine. Your engine itself would be a shared library (.dll or .so) and the blank executable would simply be a wrapper that loads the shared library and invokes a function in it with a pointer to something in it's data section.

Generating your user's executable would comprise loading the appropriate blank, making platform-specific modifications to it to tell it the size of the data section you're intended to provide it with and writing your data in the appropriate format. Or, you could simply have a blank that has an embedded copy of the raw structure into which you write values, just like populating a struct in memory:

```
struct GameDefinition {
    constexpr size_t AuthorNameLen = 80;
    char author_[AutherNameLen+1];
    constexpr size_t PublisherNameLen = 80;
    char publisher_[PublisherNameLen+1];
    constexpr size_t GameNameLen = 80;
    char name_[GameNameLen+1];
    constexpr size_t QuestionLen = 80;
    constexpr size_t AnswerLen = 80;
    char question_[QuestionLen+1];
    char answer_[AnswerLen+1];
};

static GameDefinition gameDef;

#include "engine_library.h"  // for run_engine

int main() {
    run_engine(&gameDef);
}
```

You'd compile this againsst the shared-library stub for your engine, and emit it as an executable, then you'd look up the platform-specific details of the executable format, locate the position of "gameDef" in it. The you'd read the blank into memory, and write it out with the definition of "gameDef" replaced with the one based on user input.

But what many engines do is simply ship or require the user to install a compiler (Unity relies on C#). So instead of having to tweak executables and do all this crazy platform-specific stuff, they simply output a C/C++ program and compile it.

```
// game-generator
bool make_game(std::string filename, std::string q, std::string a) {
    std::ostream cpp(filename + ".cpp");
    if (!cpp.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "open failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    cpp << "#include <engine.h>\n";
    cpp << "Gamedef gd(\"" << gameName << "\", \"" << authorName << \");\n";
    cpp << "int main() {\n";
    cpp << "  gd.q = \"" << q << \"\n";
    cpp << "  gd.a = \"" << a << \"\n";
    cpp << "  RunGame(gd);\n";
    cpp << "}\n";
    cpp.close();

    if (!invoke_compiler(filename, ".cpp")) {
        std::cerr << "compile failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!invoke_linker(filename)) {
        std::cerr << "link failed\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

If "RunGame" is not part of your engine but user-supplied, then you could emit that as part of the cpp code. Otherwise, the intent here is that it's making a call into your library.

Under Linux you might compile this with

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -o ${filename}.o ${filename}.cpp
```

and then

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -o ${filename} ${filename}.o -lengine_library
```

to link it against your engine's library.

Comment: Not sure how clever it was to do this on my phone, hope it's legible.

Comment: Note: Visual studio's compiler etc are stand-alone apps that aren't built into the visual ide. The "invoke_compiler" and "invoke_linker" are functions you'll have to write, they could be as simple as `std::string args = "g++ -Wall -o " ...; system(args.c_str());` for linux and a `#ifdfef WIN32` section that does the Windows equivalent, but you'll probably want to look at finer grain control over your child processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to store some data in a Windows executable, here is one legitimate way to do it:

```
#pragma section("mydata",read,write)

typedef struct {
    wchar_t Question[256];
    wchar_t Answer[256];
} Quiz;

__declspec(allocate("mydata")) Quiz QA;
```

The `Quiz` structure will be stored in a read-write data section named `mydata` in the PE file. You can even turn the `QA` variable into an array of structures so you can have more than one question and answer pair.

Reading the user-entered data is easy — you just use `QA` variable like any other variable.

Writing the user-entered data is a bit more involved — I am not going to give you the full code, but the general steps to get you on the right track:

1. Use [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) to make a copy of your executable (you can't modify the file while it is running).
2. Use [MapAndLoad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-mapandload) function from `imagehlp.h` (link to `imagehlp.lib`) to load the executable into memory so you can parse its structure and modify it.
3. Use [LOADED_IMAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/ns-dbghelp-loaded_image) (`NumberOfSections` and `Sections` members) and [IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_section_header) (`Name` member) to locate `mydata` section.
4. Use [wcscpy_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-170) to copy question and answer to the `mydata` section.
5. Use [UnMapAndLoad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-unmapandload) to calculate new checksum, commit changes, close the file, and free resources.

On a side note, I strongly advise against using `COPY /B` to modify executables or store binary data in them.

Finally, although the example above will work fine, the best way to include binary data which you need to modify in the executable is to add it as a resource — Microsoft even has [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources) on how to use and update executable resources (with a caveat that again you cannot modify currently executing file but a copy of it).